# USB debugging is set to ON but I cannot debug on the tablet

Tags: android

I set USB debugging to ON on the system settings. Now I run my app from Eclipse by making "Run As -> Android Application" , but there is nothing happening on the tablet ! So what run configurations or something else should I do ?

NB : when I plug the tablet on the USB then there was a tooltip message stating that the driver was not installed , not found !

Answer (score 1):

If your device was not installed/reconigzed you won't be able to debug your application. You should find out why it's happening before debugging, more details about Android Debugging: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have samsung , try installing Kies. Last time i tried to install software and debug it on my tablet, Samsung Galaxy Tab II , Samsung Kies where needed.

Here is the link:
http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/